# How to reply facebook inbox message using c#/asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

i got how to read inbox on fb, but dont know how to reply using c#.

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   var fb = new FacebookClient(lblToken.Text);   
   var query = string.Format(@"SELECT message_id, author_id, body, created_time FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0)");
   dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
   parameters.q = query;
   dynamic results = fb.Get("/fql", parameters);    
   List<MyMessage> q = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyMessage>>(results.data.ToString());  
   GridView4.DataSource = q;
   GridView4.DataBind();    
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution how to reply the facebook private message. but this is only valid for facebook fan page.

Firstly it is need to have access token for page. then on clicking button, put this code:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(lblToken.Text);
    var query = string.Format(@"SELECT body,message_id,sender,participants, html_body, attachments FROM unified_message WHERE thread_id = 0 ");// and viewer_id = " + orligPage);//SELECT message_count FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0
    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
    parameters.q = query;
    dynamic results = fb.Get("551183598322481/conversations");//678999761//551183598322481
    List<Refer.MyPage> q = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Refer.MyPage>>(results.data.ToString());
    gvPageInbox.DataSource = q;
    gvPageInbox.DataBind();
```

I need this gridview to retrieve the conversation_id. so we able to view the conversation_id and the message on facebook from c# page.

after that need two textbox and one button to reply the conversation from the asp.net page:
code for front end:

```
Body :&nbsp; 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBodyMsg" runat="server" Width="420px"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; which Conversation:&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtConversationID" 
            runat="server" Width="285px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then on clicking button put this code:

```
protected void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var fb = new FacebookClient(lblToken.Text);
    var to = new Dictionary<string, object>
                                {
                                    {"id", "100000147534139"}
                                };

    var jsonSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var jsonTo = jsonSerializer.Serialize(to);
    var commentDicitonay = new Dictionary<string, object>
                                {
                                    {"id", txtConversationID.Text}, //plese enter full conversation ID// eg: t_mid.1395805167639:9ac20dbffcd33a5d13
                                    {"message" , txtBodyMsg.Text},
                                    {"to" , txtMsgTo.Text}
                                };
    fb.Post("messages/", commentDicitonay);
    lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    lblMessage.Text = "Messages Replied!";
}
```